# Running Powershell script VIA ManageEngine Desktop Central

Tags: powershell, registry

So, I'm writing a small script that checks a reg key. If it exists, it appends to a txt file the hostname, time stamp, and a message that says "INSTALLED".

If it doesn't exist, it appends to a txt file the hostname, time stamp, and a message that says "FAILED".

When I run the script locally, it works perfectly.

> $fileexists = (gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\298C69A42C20BA5468ED011DB3619B75\sourceList\Net*).1 -contains "C:\temp\pdminstaller\extracted\64bit\SOLIDWORKS PDM Client"
> If ($fileexists ) {
> $Date = Get-Date -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
> $Name = Hostname
> $Name, $Date, "INSTALLED" >> "\XXXXXX\SHARED\PDMRESULTS\EPDM CLIENT UPDATE LOG.txt"
> }else
> {$Name, $Date, "FAILED" >> "\XXXXXX\SHARED\PDMRESULTS\EPDM CLIENT UPDATE LOG.txt"}

In previous scripts, because the command is being run remotely, I've had to do an inline command, calling up the powershell.exe file first and this has worked.

> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe $fileexists = (gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\298C69A42C20BA5468ED011DB3619B75\sourceList\Net*).1 -contains "C:\temp\pdminstaller\extracted\64bit\SOLIDWORKS PDM Client"
> If ($fileexists ) {
> $Date = Get-Date -format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
> $Name = Hostname
> $Name, $Date, "INSTALLED" >> "\XXXXXX\SHARED\PDMRESULTS\EPDM CLIENT UPDATE LOG.txt"
> }else
> {$Name, $Date, "FAILED" >> "\XXXXXX\SHARED\PDMRESULTS\EPDM CLIENT UPDATE LOG.txt"}

For some reason, it's not creating the file on the specified share when running from Desktop Central.

Any ideas? I'm newbie level, so please be gentle. :)

Not sure what to do to get it to run remotely.

Comment: Please [Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code blocks properly to make them readable

Comment: Does the ManageEngine Desktop Central Agent run under an account that has access to write to the share?

Comment: That should be a bit better, sorry I'm new.  :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's set to use the system account, but that's a great question. Let me ret specifying a user account.

I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Alright, in that case the computer's own domain account (eg. `COMPUTER01$`) is likely the one that needs write access to the share :)

Comment: The local and remote computer needs to be using same account.  You are probably using Group Policy.  So user needs to be using same account on local and remote machines.  You do not automatically run as an Admin in Powershell unless you right click on the PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  When an admin on windows to have access to remote machine you use a dollar sign in the path instead of a colon.  Something like : gpHKLM$\SOFTWARE\

Comment: I changed the RUN AS account to my domain admin account and it's working :)